# Without Controller is it possible to force files to open in the browser instead of downloading (PDF)?

Tags: c#, html, google-chrome

> In a href I have given the file link which is stored in azure. when I click the link from Chrom it prompts to download instead of opening in a new tab.

Your kind answer will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible as that.
For example if you wants to start your file on firefox you can use that, for chrome just change `chrome` instead of `firefox`

code:

```
var runningProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("firefox");
if (runningProcess.Length != 0)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("firefox", filename);
}
```

Comment: ohh, sorry @Mahmud i missed to yellow area :)
So your problem isnt about C# you can solve it with chrome like that:
1- Download file once. And check status bar on bottom of Chrome when download done
2- Click to arrow next of download file in status bar.
3-Then select "always open files of this type" it will work as u want.